# How does JS understand props parameter as object in any function (react.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object

While i am studying react.js, i noticed that any function i wrote and then give it any parameter name, javascript will understand this parameter as **object type**

Like this :

```
function Somthing(some){
    return (
        <div>
            Hello, friends{console.log(some)}
        </div> 
    ) 
}

export default Something;
```

Then `console.log(some)` will give me "Object{}" type without assigning to it any object

So my question, How can i do this concept in vanilla javascript and how does javascript understand it?

Comment: `some` will hold an object containing all props passed to the `Somthing` component when it's rendered. It's the React library/framework that actually calls your function, not you - and React will always call it with an object as its only argument.

Comment: Note this is only true if it's rendered as a React component, e.g. using JSX. If you just called it directly `Something(123)` then `some` would be a number. There's no magic here.

Comment: oh yeah sorry i forgot JSX role here!! Thanks friend @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

You can think of **[React props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)** as a normal function parameter , its an object contains some properties.

in next example we see , react components or jsx are normal **[constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#examples)**

```
function Greeting(props){
        return <h3>Hello {props.name}</h3>
}
```

When you insert your Greeting component inside your App or parent component like this:

```
function App (){
 return <Greeting name="Jack" />
}
```

what happen under the hood that **[Babel](https://babeljs.io/)** compile the code to something like this

```
function Greeting(props) {
  return React.createElement("h3", null, "Hello ", props.name);
}
```

and App Component complied to something like this

```
function App() {
      return React.createElement(Greeting, {
        name: "Jack"
      });
    }
```